# How to reverse a transformation by matrix in Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, blender

I have a selected mesh (creatively called 'selected') which I want to work with in its local space so I use the following:

```
    tmesh = NMesh.GetRawFromObject(selected.name)
    tmesh.transform(selected.matrix)
```

I then do a bunch of calculations on its verticies and remove them by index, which works great.

What doesn't work so great is when I try to add them back later from a list of vert.co objects. They end up being positioned correctly relative to each other, but nowhere near the original verticies.

> ```
>             for v in tmesh.verts:
>                  toAdd.append(v.co)
>               mesh = selected.getData(mesh=1)
>               mesh.verts.extend(toAdd)
> ```

I realized this is because the object is in a different space. So I *think* what I need to do is translate the new verticies back to the old space... but my understanding of what exactly is going on here is fuzzy at best. How do I "undo" the tmesh.transform(selected.matrix) command?

A more thoroug explanation of what I'm doing can be found here: http://www.kellbot.com/2010/11/lego-plans-now-with-better-rendering/

Comment: Can you leave the `tmesh.transform(selected.matrix)` out before doing your "bunch of calculations on its vertices"? i.e. Work in the object's space and avoid the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Blender specfically, but after a quick peek at the documentation, in principle it seems like you ought to be able to use the [`invert()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/249PythonDoc/Mathutils.Matrix-class.html#invert) `Matrix` method to obtain the inverse transformation of the `selected.matrix` (perhaps after first making a [`copy()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/249PythonDoc/Mathutils.Matrix-class.html#copy) of it).